# Browser can't connect after wakeup from sleep in Windows 10, but other protocols seem fine

Tags: networking, windows-10, http

I have been seeing an odd problem since a few weeks ago. My Win 10 PC has TP-Link wifi adapter card installed. Nothing changed as I am aware, but everytime after restart or wake up from sleep, any browser can't connect to any web page, which means the HTTP is not working until after about 3 minutes.

Oddly, seems apps using other protocols are fine, like music streaming app and games.

Anybody had this same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run Windows built-in network troubleshooter.

And then check your configuration:

1. Open Device Manager.
2. Right click your wifi adapter choose properties.
3. Find the "power management" tab.
4. Uncheck the box that allows the computer to turn off the adapter to save power.
5. Putting your device to sleep for test.

Also reference here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/wi-fi-wont-reconnect-after-sleep-or-hibernation/e5c5c60a-5787-4963-84cd-1ada6317b617